# Dynamically added edit text in found repeatedly after view is scroll down in list view in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using a list view which contain an question textview and two button, Yes and No. When i click on the no button then another layout shows, contain edittext. 
Here is my code for list view adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.questions_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.question = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.question);
        holder.questionNo = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.questionNo);
        holder.yesBtn = (ImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
        holder.noBtn = (ImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.noButton);
        holder.subQuestionLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.subQuestionLayout);
        holder.subQuestion = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.subQuestion);
        holder.subQuestionAnswer = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.subQuestionAnswer);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    setUpListeners(holder, position);
    return convertView;
}


private void setUpListeners(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.yesBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                        holder.subQuestionLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);



        }

    });

    holder.noBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                                holder.subQuestionLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            // set subquestions
                            holder.subQuestion.setText(questionsModel.get(position)
                                .getQuestion_subquestion().get(0).getText().toString());
                        }
                }

            }


        }
    });
```

I am using the above code. When i am click no button for the first question the dynamic layout shows, then i tried to scroll down but the same layout will displays on the 6th question also. 
How can i resolved it?? Please helpme

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add this line to getView() as well:
holder.subQuestionLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
This will make sure the 'initial' state of your view is GONE.
In a ListView, the views are reused. In your case the first item will be reused for the sixth item, that is why the view is VISIBLE instead of GONE.

Comment: no, when i used the  holder.subQuestionLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);  in the getView(), then view which is already visible also went to invisible after view is scrolled down.

Comment: In that case, you could add an int to your adapter or a List<Integer> which holds the positions of the items with the view as VISIBLE. In getView() you can check if the current position matches that one, and set the visibility to VISIBLE if yes, to GONE if no.

Answer (score 0):

We must think each item of the list as separate object. Often we need to maintain states of these objects. For example if the background of 7th item is changed to RED then obviously we expect that item to stay in it's state(RED) whenever it becomes visible while scrolling back and forth.

In case of `ListView`, `View`s are just used to show the object and are recycled. So its wrong to rely on `View`s to maintain states. Rather we can maintain states in the model object. Just before returning `View` in `getView()` examine the state and configure your `View` accordingly.

In your case the model class would be something like `Question`. In that class add two `boolean`s namely `yesClicked` and `noClicked`.

```
private void setUpListeners(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

  holder.yesBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Question q = //Get the object for position.
        //This logic can change according to your need. I just write this by guess.
        q.yesClicked = true;
        q.noClicked = false;
    }

  });

  holder.noBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Question q = //Get the object for position.
        //This logic can change according to your need. I just write this by guess.
        q.noClicked = true;
        q.yesClicked = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Modify your `getView()` as follows

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     //All other stuffs

     Question q = //Get the object for position.
     if(q.yesClicked){
          holder.subQuestionLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
     if(q.noClicked){
          holder.subQuestionLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          // set subquestions
          holder.subQuestion.setText(questionsModel.get(position)
                  .getQuestion_subquestion().get(0).getText().toString());
     }
     return convertView;
 }
```